# Unable to select Nvidia proprietry driver (greyed out)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary

I have just completed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am using a minimal install and enabled the use of proprietary drivers during installation.

Upon boot and logging in my resolution was set at 1024x768 and I cannot change it. I went to the Additional Drivers page of Software & Updates, but continuing to use my manually installed driver is both the selected option and only one that is not greyed out.

I have read that the fix for this is `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but this then prompts me to `Media change: please insert the disc labeled 'Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819)' in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]`, but this CD media does not exist (I installed via USB) and I have not seen mention of this on other topics. Inserting this does not help.

How do I resolve my graphics issue and switch to the proprietary drivers listed?

I am using a GeForce GTX 980 Ti.

Comment: Well, actually `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is not a fix, but a way to install the recommended nvidia driver for a supported card. Perhaps yours is not supported - for example, too old. Which card model do you have???

Comment: For the NVidia driver, one option is to download it from NVidia's web site [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx).  When you select your card, is a Linux driver offered to you?

Comment: @mikewhatever a GeForce GTX 980 Ti

Comment: My GTX 970 is using the Nvidia 495 driver from the standard repositories, but the 470 driver is the one that is "tested" from the "Additional Drivers" list.  Both should work.